# How can I create a PHP 'Download will begin shortly' page?

Tags: php

I'd like to create a PHP page which shows a message like

```
Your download will begin shortly.

If it does not start, please click here to restart the download
```

i.e., the same type of page that exists on major websites.

It will work like this:

```
<a href="download.php?file=abc.zip">Click here</a>
```

When the user clicks that link, he is led to download.php which shows him that message, and then offers the file for download.

How can I do this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link needs to do one of two things:

- point directly to the file on your web server
- point to a PHP script which will do NOTHING but set the appropriate headers and serve the file as the page body.  No text output!  See http://teddy.fr/blog/how-serve-big-files-through-php for how to actually serve the file.

One way to get the browser to start the download "on its own" is to use a META REFRESH tag.

Another way is to use JavaScript, such as this (from Mozilla's Firefox download page):

```
function downloadURL() {
    // Only start the download if we're not in IE.
    if (download_url.length != 0 && navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE') == -1) {
        // 5. automatically start the download of the file at the constructed download.mozilla.org URL
        window.location = download_url;
    }
}

// If we're in Safari, call via setTimeout() otherwise use onload.
if ( navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Safari') != -1 ) {
    window.setTimeout(downloadURL, 2500);
} else {
    window.onload = downloadURL;
}
```

Comment: See this page for example:

http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/products/download.html?product=firefox-3.6.6&os=win&lang=en-US

That HAS text output, and yet the file goes up for download. I want to duplicate something like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
// download.php
$url = 'http://yourdomain/actual/download?link=file.zip'; // build file URL, from your $_POST['file'] most likely
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- 5 seconds -->
          <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; url=<?php echo $url;?>" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Download will start shortly.. or <a href="<?php echo $url;?>">click here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure the file will be downloaded (as opposed to shown in the browser or a browser plugin), you can set the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header. For example, to force PDFs to download instead of opening in the browser plugin:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="foo.pdf"');
readfile('foo.pdf');
```